# Applet ClassNotFoundException - Relative Path?

Tags: java, path, applet, relative-path

I use this to display an applet in Gadgets.jsp

```
<applet codebase="../../WEB-INF/classes" code="Gadgets/calculator.class" width="200" height="280">
If your browser was Java-enabled, a Calculator would appear here.
</applet>
```

But it displays a ClassNotFoundException...
I also tried

```
<applet codebase="../WEB-INF/classes" code="Gadgets/calculator.class" width="200" height="280">
If your browser was Java-enabled, a Calculator would appear here.
</applet>
```

But it still displays a ClassNotFoundException...
This is my folder structure:
web - View - Gadgets.jsp

- web
- - View
- - - Gadgets.jsp
- - WEB-INF
- - - classes
- - - - Gadgets
- - - - - calculator.class

What is the correct relative path for `codebase`?

Comment: `WEB-INF` content is not accessible to client (browser).

Comment: @Pshemo then how can I reference the class for a JApplet?

Comment: Try to create separate directory for resources available to client (like images) outside of `WEB-INF`, make sure that `.class` file of applet will be placed there and point to that location in HTML.